# С двумерного массива получить вектор сум

Tags: c++, матрицы

Для двумерного массива размером N * M получить вектор из сумм отрицательных элементов каждого столбца матрицы.
Как это сделать?
Вот код ввода матрицы:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    setlocale(0, "");
    srand(time(NULL));
    int M, N, i, j;
    cout << "Введите количество столбцов:" << endl;
    cin >> M;
    cout << "Введите количество строк:" << endl;
    cin >> N;
    double** A = new double* [M];
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        A[i] = new double[N];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            A[i][j] = 5 - rand() % 10;
            cout << setw(3) << A[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну пройдите по каждому столбцу да просуммируйте отрицательные элементы внутри столбца. В чём сложность? Будет такой же цикл в цикле как по отображению матрицы. Ну, практически.

Comment: И у вас что-то не то с вложенным циклом. Один из циклов должен быть до `N`, а не до `M`, кажется внутренний.

Comment: Второй раз я не это не поведусь.

Answer (score 1):

Вы запутались в размерах строк и столбцов, поэтому придайте их осмысленные имена, а не N и M, чтобы самим не запутаться и других не запутать. А если `М` есть размер столбцов, а `N`размер строк, тогда:

```
std::vector<int> sum(M);
for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        if (A[i][j] < 0)
            sum[j] += A[i][j];
```

Comment: Судя по выделению памяти, то должно быть `i < M` и `j < N` в первом цикле. Хотя у ТС ввод количеств столбцов используеться как количество строк. Бардак в коде у ТС вобщем)

Comment: @EOF, верно, я не посмотрел, я смотрел сообщения перед вводом, а по этим сообщениям наоборот